# rhotic sound in received pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, rhoticity

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcaWkR4ydeY

Hi, This is a British pronunciation according to the title. I can hear a rhotic /ɝ/ in the second syllable, however.

In the pronunciation of this word, there's almost no difference between British English and American English?

Can you tell is it British English or American English only from the voice of this word?

Comment: It's British pronunciation, not because of the rhotic sound or lack thereof in that video, but because of the high rising terminal.

Comment: Definitely British. No way it's RP; southern, yes. It's a kind of Estuary with a hint of West Country.

Comment: @Michael Harvey I'm afraid you won't make a Professor Henry Higgins! :) The accent is East Midlands... It says so in the comments below the video...

Comment: There are no comments; the Collins caption says '_English_ Midlands', it's wrong (I spent my childhood in Derby, where my father was born).

Answer (score 3):

> Hi, This is a British pronunciation according to the title. I can hear a rhotic /ɝ/ in the second syllable, however.

The word in question is *generation.* Non-rhoticity does not affect /r/s that are followed by another vowel, as happens in that word (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English)).

> Can you tell is it British English or American English only from the voice of this word?

Yes, probably, but only because of differences in vowel quality, not because of anything related to rhoticity.

Comment: OP's point is that we don't usually see r-coloured vowels in non-rhotic English. As it goes this is an overgeneralisation, because we occasionally have syllabic /r/ in RP/SSBE/GB. ***However***, this is not one of those instances! OP has merely misheard. There's no [ɝ] in the second syllable at all.